# Can't read text file from filepath

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make javascript read a .txt file that contains links to websites, and with that can I press a button to get sent to a random website.

But my code won't work, I have tried a lot of things...

Here is my code

```
<script>
    var sites = [];
    function readTextFile(file, callback) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    alert(allText);
                    callback(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    readTextFile("file:../Nicklas Behrend/Desktop/links.txt", filesText =>{
        sites = filesText.split('\n');
    });

    function randomSite() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
        location.href = sites[i];
    }
</script>
```

At this part it says

> expression statement is not assignment or call

```
readTextFile("file:../Nicklas Behrend/Desktop/links.txt", filesText =>{
    sites = filesText.split('\n');
});
```

When I press the button that I made, I get to a site that says `"404 not found"`

Comment: Can't make ajax call to file protocol....needs to be a web path

Comment: Okay, sorry but i'm pretty new to this... how do i do that?

Comment: if the file is in same directory as the page is ...just use the file name

Comment: use the `Filesystem` Api

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access file protocol (`file:`) using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Meaning the file you are trying to access must be uploaded to a server and get the path (e.g., `http://...`) before you can get it through `XMLHttpRequest`.